# Adding anchor tag to |page filter in October CMS using Twig

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

So October CMS uses twig and has |page filter that creates a link to a page using the page file name (https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/filter-page)

But how do i link an anchor tag ? The documentation doesnt cover this.

I want below:

```
a href="{{ 'about'|page }}">About Us</a>
```

To be like:

```
a href="{{ 'about#myanchor'|page }}">About Us</a>
```

Comment: Anchors are not an issue for the backend of a site and are never send towards the server. So you just can use `<a href="{{ 'about'|page }}#myanchor">About Us</a>`

Comment: Fantastic thanks wonder why the documentation doesn't cover this